# Function that returns the sum of the number of dividers without remainder of a number, C

Tags: c, function, loops, modulus, divide

I could easily print what I wanted in a loop, but I'm new to functions and I need to save or return the sum of the dividers that have no remainder to a number which is an input of the user.

Example:

Input - `6`

Output - `1+2+3=6`

How I started:

```
int NumberOfDividers(int number)
{
    int i,num, count = 0;
    num = number;
    for ( i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        if ((num % i) == 0) //so now I know i is one of the dividers i want to save.

    }
}
```

So if `i` is one of the dividers I want, how can I save it into a variable? Or an array?

Comment: You're already declaring a bunch of variables, just declare another one to hold the sum and add to it as you go, returning it in the end.

Comment: @EricRenouf I think he wants to save these numbers(dividers).

Comment: @Gilad is it necessary that the sum of the numbers should be equal to the input?

Comment: @asfandahmed1 I was just going from the title that wants to return the sum of those numbers, which could be done by saving an array and then summing that later, but if what you want is to return the sum that seems unnecessary

Comment: i want to save each of the dividers, for example the number 6. i need to save 1,2,3. can i do this in an array? without knowing the number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this way...

```
//other headers as you need
#include<string.h>//this header is for memset
int dividers[1000];//global array
int currPos;//global variable
int NumberOfDividers(int number)
{

   int i,num, count = 0;
   num = number;
   for ( i = 1; i < num; i++)//you should start counting from 1 otherwise you will get floating point exception
   {
       if ((num % i) == 0)
       {
           dividers[currPos]=i;//putting the dividers in the array
           currPos++;//updating the pivot where the next dividers will stay
       }
   }
   return 0;
}

int main()
{
    memset(dividers,0,sizeof(dividers));//initializing the array
    currPos=0;//initializing the variable to point at the start of the array
    NumberOfDividers(6);
    int i;
    int sum=0;
    for(i=0;i<currPos;i++)
    {
       printf("%d",dividers[i]);
       sum+=dividers[i];
       if(i!=currPos-1)
       {
           printf("+");
       }
   }
   printf("=%d\n",sum);
   return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

To return the sum of the proper divisors, do:

```
int sum_of_proper_divisors (int number)
{
    int sum = 0;
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i < number; i++)
    {
        if ((number % i) == 0) 
           sum += i;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

You just need to use the return keyword to return the value.

Comment: i want to save each of the dividers, for example the number 6. i need to save 1,2,3. can i do this in an array? without knowing the number?

Comment: @Gilad , I have given an answer. Please take a look.

Answer (score 2):

As this task looked fun to do, did not want to take away the coding experience.  Instead laid out a sample algorithm that should code in C fairly directly.

Pseudo-code

```
int *NumberOfDividers(int number)
  find isqrt(number) --> sqrt_number
  sqrt_number*2 + 2 --> max_array_count
  allocate int[] with max_array_count elements
  validate allocation
  starting at divisor = 1, in a loop ...
    quotient = number/divisor
    remainder = number%divisor
    if (remainder == 0)
      add divisor to list
      if (divisor != quotient) add quotient to list
    if (divisor >= quotient) quit loop
    divisor++
  append 0 to list to indicate the end
  shrink array to needed size if desired
  validate shrink result
  return array pointer.
```

Notice the loop does at most `sqrt(number)` iterations, so a reasonable upper bound of the needed array size can be calculated before using any divisors.

Also see [How many positive integers are factors of a given number?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/295465/how-many-positive-integers-are-factors-of-a-given-number) for more advanced ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You can see an another way to do this. This will work very fast for a vast amount of data. Here is my way and you can follow this to find this in a fastest way to find the sum of factors of a number. Here is my code:

```
int number_of_divisor(int n)
{
    int sum_of_factors=0;
    sum_of_factors+=1;//as 1 is factor of all num
    //sum_of_factors+=n;//n will always a factor of n

    for(int i = 2; i * i <= n; ++i)
    {
        if(n % i == 0)
        {
            sum_of_factors+=i;
            if(i * i != n)
                sum_of_factors+=(n/i);
        }
    }
    return sum_of_factors;
}
```

if your input is `long` then change all `int` by `long`.

Thank you.